# How to define and create iphone's address book db in my App with sqlite3？

Tags: iphone, sqlite, addressbook

I want to copy iphone's addressbook db into my iOS app db.

And how to define the db table with multiple phoneLabel and different phone numbers?

Answer (score 0):

2 lines for a such big problem !!

1. Learn more about CoreData (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-TP1)
2. Create your a Model "Contacts Adress Book"
3. Import CoreData.frameWork in your project (API Apple)
4. Play with CoreData , Model, Entity and Context
5. Using AdressBook.framework (API Apple) to read your addressBook.